# What is alias etale map?

Tags: etale-cohomology

I think that etal map, is a local homeomorphism(or a local diffeomorphism for manifolds). I want a reference that explain alias etale map.

Comment: See [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/etale+map) for etale map.